# Change notification settings for Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, notifications

We all know the notification settings for profiles, but is there also one for my own page?

When I click on **Notification Settings** in the notification section of my page, I get redirected to the settings of my own profile - or when I'm using Facebook as the page itself, it wants me to change to my private profile.

It's kind of annyoing to get all the notifications just because someone likes my post. I only want to get notified when someone comments or posts on my wall - in other words, when it's really important for me!

Someone has a solution for that?

Comment: Did this ever get worked out? Driving me nuts having to trawl through hundreds of likes, just to find a few comments. Amazing that there isn't a feature on FB to device WHAT you get notified of???

Comment: unfortunately no changes yet...

Comment: Damn it - you would think that it would be a feature lots of people ask for! Even with a small group its pretty unmanageable (no wonder so much spam gets through on big groups/pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about granularity of like/post/comment. But I was able to turn off notifications from my Facebook Page, when I'm logged as me.

- on that Facebook Page, click "Edit Page" in top right area and in the dropdown click on "Manage Notifications"
- you should get to settings page that is entitled by name of the Facebook Page
- there is "Onsite Notification" checkbox, which you can uncheck

Comment: ah, lol, just noticed how old this question is...

Comment: basically you're right though :)

Answer (score 0):

Goto http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=Facebook&t uncheck "Email Frequency", and you can now select what notifications you wish to receive.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. I'm not talking about  notifications via email, but the notifications you see in the notification error on the top left when you're logged in as the page. I don't want to get notificated in any way when someone likes something from my page!